# Passing ID from Laravel show to Datatables route

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, datatables

I believe I am close but struggling on how to pass a given ID from my show method into the associated showdata one so that datatables can manifest with the associated data for just that ID.

The code works when I hardcode an ID or just remove the where statement altogether. My objective is to have the datatable manifest associated items for just a given collection.

Routes:

```
Route::resource('collections', 'CollectionsController');
Route::get('collectionsdata/{id}', 'CollectionsController@showdata');
```

Show.blade.php:

```
var id = {{ $collection->id }}
        $(function () {...

$('#item-table').DataTable({
                //processing: true,
                serverSide: true,
                ajax: "/collectionsdata/"+ id,
                columns: [
                    //{data: 'id', name: 'id'},
                    {data: 'id', name: 'id'},
                    {data: 'collection_id', name: 'collection_id'},
                    {data: 'type_id', name: 'type_id'},
                    {data: 'collection.title', name: 'collection.title'},
                    {data: 'type.name', name: 'type.name'},
                    {data: 'updated_at', name: 'updated_at'},
                ]
            });
```

Collections Controller:

```
    public function show(Collection $collection)
    {
        $collection->load('items.type')->get();

        //dd($collection);
        return view ('collections.show', compact('collection'));
    }

    public function showdata()
    {
        $data = Item::with('collection', 'type')->where('collection_id', $id);

        return Datatables::of($data)->make(true);
    }
```

SHOW itself function well, var id works well in the blade - I think I am just missing something in the controller to take in the id and ultimately create the desired query on $data for return to the datatable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You are missing the **Request $request** in your show method to retrieve the $id from the route.

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

public function showdata(Request $request)
{
    $collection_id = $request->id;

    $data = Item::with('collection', 'type')->where('collection_id', $id);

    return Datatables::of($data)->make(true);
}
```

You can also retrieve **id** directly from the controller instead of using **$request**.

```
public function showdata($id)
{
    $data = Item::with('collection', 'type')->where('collection_id', $id);

    return Datatables::of($data)->make(true);
}
```

Comment: You can find me in my cave of sorrows...thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

You only have to have one parameter in showdata that is one for id you are passing from URL

```
public function showdata($id)
{
    $data = Item::with('collection', 'type')->where('collection_id', $id);
    return Datatables::of($data)->make(true);
}
```